# Conexion a GCP desde ETL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, etl

Hola a todos buen dia,

requiero de su ayuda con un inconveniente, tengo una ETL hecha en Visual Studio Community con el SSIS que maneja el software. Requiero que desde ella se realice una conexión a una db que tengo en Google Cloud, alguna conoce alguna forma de lograr esta conexión?

Agradezco la colaboracion.

Alguna manera dentro de las herramientas que maneja este sistenma de ETL para conectarlo a GCP de tal forma que pueda traer dicha data y poblar una tabla en un servidor MS SQ, para despues continuar con el proceso de tratamiento de dicha data.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.